# ¿Tengo problema al hacer un INSERT con php y mysqli?

Tags: php, mysql

tengo esto

```
mysqli_query($conect,"INSERT INTO Clientes 
(Nombre,Apellido,Direccion,Provincia,Ciudad,Fono,Email,
nombreEnv,apellidoEnv,provinciaEnv,ciudadEnv,
direccionEnv,fonoEnv,emailEnv,Emailusua) VALUES 
('$nombre','$apellido','$direccion','$provincia',
'$ciudad','$fono','$email','$nombre1','$apellido1',
 '$direccion1','$provincia1','$ciudad1','$fono1','$email1')") or 
 die(mysqli_error());
```

la conexion viene de

```
$conect = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1","root","root","Homocervcerus") or 
die ("No se encontro el servidor");
```

y me da este error

```
Warning: mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given
```

tengo otro insert igual a este y ese si funciona pero este no y me da este error y no se a que se debe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes pasarle la conexión a `mysqli_error()`:

```
die(mysqli_error($conect));
```

Con eso, ahora debería reportar correctamente el verdadero error con tu `INSERT`.
Sospecho que el siguiente error será debido a la columna `Enviado/No_enviado`. No creo que le guste el `/` en el nombre, de modo que tienes que escaparlo con las comillas inversas:

```
`Enviado/No_enviado`
```

Código completo:

```
mysqli_query($conect,"INSERT INTO Factura 
(Nombre,email,provincia,ciudad,direccion,Subtotal,Envio
,Iva,Total,pago,provinciaenvio,ciudadenvio,direccionenvio
,`Enviado/No_enviado`) VALUES 
('$nombre','$email','$provincia','$ciudad','$direccion'
,'$suma','$envio','$iva','$totals','$text'
,'$provincia1','$ciudad1','$direccion1','No evnviado')")or 
 die(mysqli_error($conect));
```

Comment: gracias pana eso mismo era te agradezco mil

Comment: bro @sstan edite mi pregunta porque me salio error en otro insert pero este no tiene porblemas con la conexion ni con algun caracter raro no se que le pasa

Comment: 1) No es correcto cambiar la pregunta cuando en realidad lo que estás haciendo es una pregunta distinta, porque esto hace que las respuestas existentes pierdan su sentido.  2) Volvistes a hacer el mismo error de no pasar la conexión a `mysqli_error`.

Comment: man una pregunta que pasa si en una tabla no se inserta los datos pero no me da error que peude ser